# Elastic Search Geotile - Sort by distance when size limit reached

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation, elastic-stack, geo, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am working on the Elastic Search with Geotile aggregation and having a problem, that is the number of bucket I have may be very high (after even filtering using bounding box).

This can exceed 10,000 buckets. As the [document said](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-geotilegrid-aggregation.html#_options_5) it will take the group whose number of documents is the highest. Also, I don't want to increase the default config of size, because it may affect the performance.

However, I just want to keep the groups which is most nearest to an input point. How should I make the query to achieve this?

Thank you!

I have tried to search on:

- [Geotile aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-geotilegrid-aggregation.html#_options_5)
- [Geo sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/sort-search-results.html#geo-sorting)

Comment: Can you describe your use case. What are you doing with the results?

Comment: In my case, I want to group all the geopoint into markers using geogrid. However, all the markers are not needed to be used, because the frontend view is limited. So I just want to take the markers (bucket) nearest the centroid point of frontend view.